# Android what is the name of standard drawable 3 lines vertical

Tags: android, drawable

I need to know what is the name of the attached icon in R.android.drawable resources to use it in my app[image]

Comment: cannot you browse `<sdk>/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable*` folders?

Comment: It's the *`overflow`* icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in case you are using v4/v7 support library, you should find it with below name : 
>          android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha
>   or
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_overflow_material
>
> in case of design libary :
>   android.support.design.R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_overflow_material